# Need to load pdf/doc file in new tab, not to download just want to read in browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have added few doc/pdf files into my WordPress website.

http://209.213.121.58/~harvardm/ check Footer links under POLICIES section.

i want all of them should load in a new tab in any browser. i used `target="_blank"` but when i click on my links it's open in new tab and automatically start downloading doc/pdf files. I just want to load my files in new tab to read them on browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `.docx` or any other format it will download automatically.

Convert the file to `pdf` and use.

Should be

```
http://209.213.121.58/~harvardm/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Website%20Terms%20of%20Use.docx">
                                                                                      ^^^^
```

Comment: @Moderator...Apparently I cant type faster than you

Comment: Yeah, it was helpful. @Moderator

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert you Word .docx files to PDF in order for them to open in the browser.